# Linked List insertion issue

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was trying out Linked List and I have a bit of problem with my insertNode1 function. This function is supposed to insert a new node after the inputted node by the user. The result doesn't show what I wanted to show. I wanted the number 5 to be after 3, but it doesn't show how I wanted it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class List {
    struct node {
        float data;
        node* next;
    };
    node* head;
public:
    void appendNode(float);
    void insertNode(float);
    void insertNode1(float,float);
    void deleteNode(float);
    void displayList();
    List(){

        head = NULL;
    }
    ~List(){
        node *nodePtr, *nextNode;
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr != NULL){
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nextNode; 
        }
    }
};


void List::appendNode(float d)
{
    node *newNode, *nodePtr;
    newNode = new node; 
    newNode->data = d;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (!head){
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next){
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }

}

void List::insertNode(float d){
    node *newNode, *nodePtr, *prevNode=NULL;
    newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = d;
    if (head== NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->data < d){
            prevNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (prevNode == NULL){
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
        else {
            prevNode->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
    }
}

void List::insertNode1(float p, float d){
    node *newNode, *nodePtr, *selectedNode=NULL;
    newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = d;
    nodePtr = head;
    selectedNode = nodePtr;
    selectedNode->data = p;

    if (head != NULL){
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        while (nodePtr->next != NULL && nodePtr->data != p){
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (selectedNode == NULL){
            head = newNode;
            selectedNode->next = NULL;
        }
        else {

            selectedNode->next = newNode;

        }
    }
}

void List::deleteNode(float da){
    node *nodePtr, *previousNode=NULL;
    if (head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (head ->data == da){
        nodePtr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nodePtr;
    }
    else{
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->data != da){
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
    }

}

void List::displayList(){
    node *nodePtr;
    nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr!= NULL){
        cout << nodePtr->data << endl;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}


int main(){
    List lobj;
    lobj.appendNode(3);
    lobj.appendNode(6.4);
    lobj.appendNode(4.5);
    lobj.appendNode(7.8);
    lobj.insertNode(1.5);
    lobj.displayList();
    cout << "after deleting and adding a new node" << endl;
    lobj.deleteNode(6.4);
    lobj.displayList();
    lobj.insertNode1(3, 5);
    lobj.displayList();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your `void List::insertNode1(float p, float d)` function:

```
nodePtr = head;
selectedNode = nodePtr;
selectedNode->data = p;
```

Here, `selectedNode` points at the `head` of the list and you seem to overwrite the data of that node with the value of `p`, which I cannot help but feel is not what you meant to do.

Comment: Yea @haavee that's definitely not what I wanted to do. I'll re-read and redo this function and fix the errors necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues inside `List::insertNode1`.

```
nodePtr = head;
selectedNode = nodePtr;
selectedNode->data = p;
```

Here `selectedNode` points at `head` but then you set the first data value to p.

```
if (head != NULL){
    head = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
}
```

This part only executes when `head` is not null. This means you get rid of the entire list every time this is run. This is why the last call to `list::displayList` only prints `5`.

```
if (selectedNode == NULL){
    head = newNode;
    selectedNode->next = NULL;
}
```

Here `selectedNode` is `NULL`. first you set `head` to be a new node but this doesn't change selectedNode. If you ran this method on an empty list your program would segfault here. You should be setting the next of `head` or `newNode` to `NULL` here, not `selectedNode`.

```
else {
    selectedNode->next = newNode;
}
```

Here `selectedNode` still points to `head`. You change `nodePtr` but this doesn't also change `selectedNode`.

Comment: Ohhhhh So that's why I keep getting this output. Thanks so much :D. I will fix the errors pointed out.